# How does Expo manage installed libraries?

Tags: react-native, expo

Just trying to understand how Expo works and curious how does Expo manage installed libraries and why it does no affect on an app when I make some breaking changes in the library's files?

Are all libraries with the native code that expo supports included in the SDK? If so - why do I need to run e.g. `expo install expo-notifications` to be able to use notifications API?

Comment: it help your app use less resources, so you have choose muilple option as expo package or libary comunity, if i want some libary i willl install it

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You must run "expo install ..." to install the Expo SDK API and place them in your node-module folder and use them in your project later on.

First, let's talk about [unimodules](https://docs.expo.io/bare/unimodules-full-list/). These are Expo SDK APIs that can be used in any react native project ( expo managed, expo bare, and react native, even in [flutter](https://blog.expo.io/flutter-unimodules-bb66b9bf21de)).

In expo-managed, some of the APIs are included. As of April 2, 2021, you can see the following expo SDK API aka unimodules are included in the node-modules folder at project creation:

[image: list of expo SDK API at expo managed project]

1. [expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo#expo)
2. expo-application
3. expo-asset
4. expo-constants
5. expo-error-recovery
6. expo-file-system
7. expo-font
8. expo-keep-awake
9. expo-linear-gradient
10. expo-linking
11. expo-location
12. expo-permissions
13. expo-secure-store
14. expo-sqlite
15. expo-status-bar

Among them, you can only see ***expo*** and ***expo-status-bar*** are listed on your package.json. Other modules are not included. If you want more expo SDK API ( unimodules ) you've to install it using "expo install ..."

For using Expo SDK API in a project other than expo managed project, you need to install the npm package ***react-native-unimodules***.

Expo bare project and react native project are almost the same. However, Expo bare got react-native-unimodules installed at project creation. So you can use any Expo SDK API by installing it through "expo install ".
But for a react-native project, you have to install the npm package react-native-unimodules. Then you can install the Expo SDK APIs using "expo install ".

Although it is not said anywhere, it can be guessed they are not included in all of their expo SDK APIs because the project can become heavier. Expo is doing a lot of work for us, already.

Take a look at their [GitHub](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/whats-in-the-sdk.md) docs.